# dc js registering double click handler in postRender

Tags: dc.js

Is there a way to track mouse double click event in dc.js like mouseover, mouseup, click, mouseout etc..

```
volumeChart.on('postRender', function() {
    chart.select('text.pie-slice').on("dbclick", function() {
    console.log('dbclick')
    caught('dbclick');;
  });
});
```

Let me know the feasibility in dc js using postrender.

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: That should work - I think you've just misspelled `dblclick`. Also I'd suggest using `posttransition` instead of `postRender` so that you'll also pick up an elements added during a redraw.

Comment: Also, in general you should namespace your event listeners like `.on('dblclick.myevent', ...)` so that you don't stomp on dc.js's own event listeners - won't matter for `dblclick` but `mouseover` and others are definitely used.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it works fine for pie chart. Still bubble chart has some issue. Is the posttransition property defined?? Are you mentioning about postRedraw?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are using the [wrong selector](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/Chart-selectors) for the bubble chart? It's different for every chart.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.. I referred the link provided and is very helpful.